# set type of a property based on an enum type value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've a type `FieldType` which is an enum and `FieldTypeToTSType` which gets a `FieldType` as a parameter and converts it to the typescript type.

```
type FieldType = "string" | "int";

type FieldTypeToTSType<T extends FieldType> = 
    T extends "string" ? string
  : T extends "int" ? number
  : never;
```

but the problem is using it directly works:

```
FieldTypeToTSType<"string"> // string
FieldTypeToTSType<"int"> // number
```

but when I'm using `FieldType` it always defines it as string

```
const a: FieldType = "int";

type K = FieldTypeToTSType<typeof a>; // string but it should be number
```

the context that I'm using it:

```
type FieldType = "string" | "int";
type FieldDefinition = {
  type: FieldType;
};

type EntityDefinition<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: FieldDefinition;
};

const makeEntity = <T>(et: { [K in keyof T]: FieldDefinition }) => et;

type FieldTypeToTSType<T extends FieldType> = T extends "string"
  ? string
  : T extends "int"
  ? number
  : never;

type EntityRefrence<T extends EntityDefinition<T>, R extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  [key in R]: FieldTypeToTSType<T[R]["type"]>;
};

const Vacation = makeEntity({
  days: {
    type: "int",
  },
  name: {
    type: "string"
  }
});

type VacationRef = EntityRefrence<typeof Vacation>;
```

VacationRef's type should be

```
type VacationRef = {
    days: number;
    name: string;
}
```

but it is:

```
type VacationRef = {
    days: string | number;
    name: string | number;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `FieldType` of source entity is widened in `makeEntity` and `EntityRefrence`. To fix this in `EntityRefrence` - use specific key instead of union of all possible keys:

```
type EntityRefrence<T extends EntityDefinition<T>> = {
  [key in keyof T]: FieldTypeToTSType<T[key]["type"]>;
};
```

In `makeEntity` - passed parameter should have generic type, so its type properly inferred and not widened:

```
const makeEntity = <T extends { [K in keyof T]: FieldDefinition }>(et: T) => et;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwCrmgXigIgM7ABOcAdgOY5QA+upwOA3AFCiSwIoAiEAZqXMDgB7ElGwBvJlCisIALnZI0GZgF9mLDFACiJQaG58SA4SQA8qAHxiok6QG0A0lFJQA1hBBCeUVAF0FeCVDfkERNQ1NNiCUdEhUIVQAZTiICygIAA9gCBJkPEVYjGtsVAzs3PzcAmJyHCkoAH4oGtIyBoUyrJy8gpw6eulmkgBXAFsAIwhCDqgSCAA3aY1ZHT0BEAAlXkJcgGM0roretf0QEOMw8ysS2wb7DxAXUUfvXwDC5XjElIwLB88fnsOFkOD8lgiTCYexEBCgYwAhh5dGcbOlupUCuIoE5nu5PG9-IEOMgLiYRFBVJYABQQYCdACUYmsdI0MJIcIAagi9girjZEcj1qBqXYoMgESA8AoxdJZAp+nocAAaBqqVXSEgIsbyO7SOUYBWtOpqpiqBkrLTc3lXbY+bAojZ23YkA5mWRva180wQoA)